# Angular data binding returning NaN when value is zero

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing some simple data binding like so:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" model="amount">
<label>Your amount is {{amount * 10 }}</label>
```

However, initially, when the text input is empty it returns NaN.

How can I prevent this from happening with Angular?

Comment: You have to watch and convert the datatype of `amount` to integer otherwise its string multiplying with 10 which will give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" model="amount">
<label>Your amount is {{ (+amount) * 10 }}</label>
```

HTML text inputs are text by definition. the added + will convert it to an number prior to being used.

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator to check isNaN in your tempalte like below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" model="amount">
<label>Your amount is {{ (!isNaN(amount)) ?  (amount * 10) : '' }}</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your amount is

```
{{ (amount * 10) || "0" }}
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your amount is {{ (amount * 10) || "0" }}

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (a*10)+b;
```

where b is undefined value.so, we are getting NaN value.

```
a = (a*10) || b;
```

this || operator instead of "+" solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it